# How to do a where on a joined table?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this query

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

$queryBuilder->select('u')
    ->join('AppBundle\Entity\Company', 'c');
    ->where('c.owners = :u.id', 'LOWER(c.name) LIKE :searchInput')
    ->setParameter('searchInput', "%" . strtolower($searchInput) . "%");
```

The goal of this query is to look for the table Compagny, check if this table have the user_id on it's owner, and if it has, to search the field name of the table Company and compare it with searchInput.

Unfortunatly I have this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 242: Error: Expected end of string, got '.'
```

Have an idea why does it happens ?

```
class Company implements CompanyModelInterface
{
    //Other properties there

    /**
     * @var UserInterface[]
     */
    protected $owners;
}
```

And my .yml

```
manyToMany:
    owners:
      targetEntity: User
      joinTable:
        name: company_owners
        schema: public
        joinColumns:
          company_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            unique: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better if you could specify the mapping of user and company in their entities like doing it as doctrine way and in join part just reference those property who are mapped to another entity

like

```
class User
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="owners")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;
}

class Company
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $owners;
}
```

Using query builder you could write as

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->select('u')
    ->join('u.company', 'c');
    ->where('c.name LIKE :searchInput')
    ->setParameter('searchInput', "%" . strtolower($searchInput) . "%");
```

For now if you haven't defined any mappings and still want to join 2 entities you can use `WITH` clause

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

$queryBuilder->select('u')
    ->join('AppBundle\Entity\Company', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.owners = u.id');
    ->where('c.name LIKE :searchInput')
    ->setParameter('searchInput', "%" . strtolower($searchInput) . "%");
```

[Mapping the ManyToOne Relationship](http://symfony.com/doc/4.0/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship)

If you are using Mysql database at backend i suggest you to set tables collation as case insensitive so that you don't need to use `LOWER/UPPER` functions

[B.5.4.1 Case Sensitivity in String Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Define your mappings as bi-directional like for user define as

```
User:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    companies:
      targetEntity: Company
      mappedBy: owners
```

For company

```
manyToMany:
    owners:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: companies
      joinTable:
        name: company_owners
        schema: public
        joinColumns:
          company_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            unique: true
```

and then you could write as

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->select('u')
    ->join('u.companies', 'c');
    ->where('c.name LIKE :searchInput')
    ->setParameter('searchInput', "%" . strtolower($searchInput) . "%");
```

Comment: I don't have the possibility anymore to map the Company table to the User one. I already tried your second solution, but it gave me the error `line 0, col 83 near 'owners = u.id': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Please double check if you have a property in company entity named as `owners` also reverse the matching criteria like `'u.id = c.owners'` and introduce `->from('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')`

Comment: Could it be because the property owners has a manytoMany relationship with the table company_owners ?

Comment: Can you include your entity definitions in your question

Comment: Yes I just did. May be should I first join company_owners and then join the company ? But I don't have no entity CompanyOwners

Comment: @DimitriDanilov No in many to many association you don't need to specify junction table (company_owners) in query, Doctrine will take care o this part , Also see updated answer